# Device Rotation Notification is not working as expected iOS Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
    func shouldirotate(){

    var whichwaywhere: String {

        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft {
            return "left"
        }
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight {
            return "right"
        }
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown {
            return "down"
        }
        return "I don't Care"
    }
    println(whichwaywhere)
}
```

when I create a function that continuously checks itself, (attaching shouldirotate to a NSTimer) I can get the orientation checked. How could I tell the function to run when UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification activates?

To get UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification running I have a variable:

```
var rotatenote: Bool = UIDevice.currentDevice().generatesDeviceOrientationNotifications
```

and in the ViewDidLoad override I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    rotatenote = true
}
```

Is this the correct way to use and declare this property?  how can I get the function to run off of DeviceOrientationNotification?

P.S.: I have rotatenote = true in the ViewDidLoad because if I try to attach it to the variable declaration like usual, it says "cannot assign to the result of this expression." See Below

```
var rotatenote: Bool = UIDevice.currentDevice().generatesDeviceOrientationNotifications = true
```

Comment: What precisely are you trying to accomplish.  Are you just wanting to do something when the orientation changes?

Comment: I am trying to switch to another ViewController when the device rotates to a position other than portrait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Not sure what OS you are worried about, but in iOS 8 you've got two easy options.  You can either register an observer for

`UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`

or you can override

`func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`

You should **not** need

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
```

So either in viewDidLoad add:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "functionThatYouWantTriggeredOnRotation", name:
        UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Where you have a function `functionThatYouWantTriggeredOnRotation` that does the calculation...

Alternatively you can just provide the override for viewWillTransition and not have to add an observer for the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize,
      withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape {
            //do your thing
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you, but you should also think about the fact that using `viewWillTransitionToSize` will change and possibly bug out when using different size phones.

Comment: what is `defaultCenter()`?

Comment: `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()` Returns the process’s default notification center.

Comment: viewWillTransitionToSize will be called on any current device, until their is a square device.  In this case, you don't actually care what the size is, you just care that it changed from 1920 x 1080 to 1080 x 1920 or viceVersa

Comment: but then don't you have to know what the size of the current device is to specify `CGSize`?

Comment: No, you do not call the function.  You just implement what you want to happen when it is called inside of the function.  The system will call this function when the device rotates and causes the size to change.

Comment: viewWillTransitionToSize occurs before the size change has occurred, which is a little different from prior methods which used to allow us to know that a change already occurred.